# How do I find the . Pr(−0.3 < z < 1.9) in R

Tags: r

I cant find the formula to calculate the Pr(−0.3 < z < 1.9)

I tried something like pnorm ([-0.3,mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE]+[1.9,mean=0,sd=1,lower.tail=TRUE])

pnorm ([-0.3,mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE]+[1.9,mean=0,sd=1,lower.tail=TRUE])

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Comment: Why the square brackets? `pnorm(1.9) - pnorm(-0.3)`.

Comment: I think you want `pnorm(1.9)-pnorm(-.3)` because `pnorm` will assume a standard normal distribution. What you've written isn't even proper R syntax. You might want to start with a basic R tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `pnorm(1.9)-pnorm(-0.3)`, Since it is a standard normal, there is no need to define the mean and the deviation. so you can get the probability of being between 1.9 and -0.3.